# bind an event to a dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have written a angularjs directive which basically draws boxes on the screen, I also display some errors in a popup in the form of a table.this table has a **Suppress** key, when suppress is pressed I wish to generate an event that I wish to handle. the problem that I am facing with the code below is, some of the suppress buttons are generating the click event others are not, these are buttons are inside the  of a div. I have no clue what is going on can someone please help. I am using the third party smallipop jquery library for the popup. Posting the directive below.

**directive**

```
    (function () {

    var canvas;
    var directive = function ($compile, $q, mddErrorPanelFactory) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                componentId: '=',
                componentName: '=',
                siteName: '=',
                popupErrorDetails: '=',
                onSuppression: '&'
            },
            templateUrl: 'shared/directives/_square_draw.html',
            link: function (scope, element) {

                var suppressKey = function (event) {
                    var key = event.data.id;
                    scope.onSuppression({ suppressedKey: key });
                }

                var generatePopupHtml = function (errors, exchangeName) {

                    var htmlContent = $('<div></div>');

                    htmlContent.append('<h5 class="panel-danger">' + exchangeName + '</h5>');
                    var table = $('<table></table>');
                    table.addClass("table").addClass("table-bordered").addClass("table-condensed").addClass("table-hover");

                    for (var index in errors) {
                        var tbody = $('<tr id="' + errors[index].id + '"/>').addClass("warning").addClass("font-colour").addClass("mdd-font-size");
                        tbody.append('<td>' + errors[index].last_update_time + '</td>')
                            .append('<td>' + errors[index].error_time + '</td>')
                            .append('<td><input type="button"' + 'id=\"' + errors[index].id + '\">Suppress</input></td>')
                            .bind("click", { id: errors[index].id  }, function (event) {
                                console.log("Event generated on click")
                                suppressKey(event);
                            });
                        table.append(tbody);
                    }
                    htmlContent.append(table);
                    return htmlContent;
                }

         scope.$watch('[componentId,componentName,popupErrorDetails,siteName]', function (newValue) {
                    $('.myElement').smallipop();
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                    if (canvas === null) {
                        canvas = document.getElementById(newValue[0] + newValue[3]);
                    }

                    canvas.id = newValue[0] + newValue[3];
                    canvas = document.getElementById(canvas.id);
                    var errors = newValue[2];
                    var tooltipSpan = $('<span class="smallipop-hint"/>');
                    tooltipSpan.append(generatePopupHtml(errors, newValue[1]));

                    var innerHtml = $('<div id="' + canvas.id + '"></div>');
                    innerHtml.append('<strong>' + newValue[1] + '</strong>');
                    innerHtml.append(tooltipSpan);

                    $('#' + canvas.id).append(innerHtml);
                }, true)
            }
        };
    };

    app.directive('squareDraw', directive);
}());
```

**_square_draw.html**

```
<div id="canvas" class="mdd-table-responsive table-bordered mdd-table-hover myElement">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Looking further it seems that only one click event is firing per div created using the ng-repeat, and click triggers the event only once.

Comment: have you tried to preventDefault? `var surpressKey = function (event) { event.preventDefault(); .... }` this should handle preventing the standard click event http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Instead of Bind, can you use the on() jQuery handler attachment method to list for event bubbling on a parent element? Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/z1vbshua/ for an example.

Comment: Hi I tried both the things recommended above, but it doesn't seem to be  working for me